# Pygame not restoring from pause

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to pause my game by pressing the 'p' key, but after it pauses it does not unpause when p is pressed again. Here are the relevant segments of my code, I'd like to know how to fix this and/or if there are better alternative methods of implementing a game pause.

```
pause = False

while True:
    if not pause:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
        #game code
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        #if key up     
        elif keys[pygame.K_p]:
            pause = True #appears to work correctly, screen freezes and
                         #prints "PAUSED" every tick.    
        #more game code
        pygame.display.update()
        fpsClock.tick(FPS)   
    else:
        print("PAUSED")
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()


            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.type == pygame.K_p:
                    pause = False
        pygame.display.update()
        fpsClock.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: `event.type` should be `event.key` when checking against `pygame.K_p`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below does the trick.

I have added in `if not pause: ... else:` section also a handler for a keypress because without it there will be no chance to come out of the pause (the part `if not pause` won't never ever be run without this keypress check if once paused).

```
import pygame
pygame.init() # start PyGame (necessary because 'import pygame' doesn't start PyGame)
colorWhite = (255, 255, 255) # RGB color for later use in PyGame commands (valueRed=255, valueGreen=255, valueBlue=255)

colorWhite = (255, 255, 255) # RGB color for later use in PyGame commands (valueRed=255, valueGreen=255, valueBlue=255)
winDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((1024, 768)) # set PyGame window size to 1024x768 pixel
pygame.display.set_caption("Minimal PyGame Test Script")
winDisplay.fill(colorWhite)

fpsClock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 15
pause   = False
pauseCounter = 0

while True:
    if not pause:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_p: 
                pause = not pause 

            #game code

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        #more game code

        pygame.display.update()
        fpsClock.tick(FPS)   
    else:
        pauseCounter += 1
        print(pauseCounter, "PAUSED")
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_p: 
                pause = not pause 
        #more game code
        pygame.display.update()
        fpsClock.tick(FPS)
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()` in the event loop. Mostly because you're calling the function for every event which is redundant since the key states doesn't change (they updates once when you call an event function). Also, in this case you're checking for a key press (not if it's held) so using the event function would be the more logical choice here `if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_p: pause = not pause`

Comment: @TedKleinBergman Thanks for your comment. I have already updated the provided code with your suggestion. The reason why it was there was because I tried not to change much of the code - only the pause part, but you are right - if providing code it should be to best knowledge ...